# Aurelia: Issue with using a shared class specification for properties in parent and child custom elements

Tags: aurelia

I have a code like below where a Project has a Timeline.

I have created a class named **TimelineProperties** which acts as a shared specification for a properties I want to pass from a project to a child Timeline.

I have planned to use **TimelineProperties** class in Project custom element like this:

```js
import {TimelineProperties} from "./timeline";

@customElement('project')
export class Project {
   timeline: TimelineProperties = new TimelineProperties();
}
```

```html
<template>
   ...
   <timeline list.bind="timeline.list" loading.bind="timeline.loading" error.bind="timeline.error" />
   ...
</template>
```

And also inside a Timeline custom element (to share code):

## Either via inheritance like this:

```js
export class Timeline extends TimelineProperties {}
```

## Or via composition like this:

```js
export class Timeline {
  // TimelineProperties class has @bindable properties defined
  timeline: TimelineProperties = new TimelineProperties();
}

// and then use bindings from project.html like this:
<timeline timeline.list.bind="timeline.list" timeline.loading.bind="timeline.loading" timeline.error.bind="timeline.error" />
```

The issue is that I cannot use a shared specification class **TimelineProperties** inside a Timeline custom element either via inheritance nor composition.

1. Issue with inheritance - https://github.com/aurelia/templating/pull/507
2. Issue with composition - Exception in runtime: "Error: Attempted to register an Element when one with the same name already exists. Name: project"

So now I have copied the **TimelineProperties** fields also into a Timeline Custom Element class (see 3 @bindable properties inside **timeline.ts** code below) just to make it work. But I would like to avoid that code duplication.

My question is, is there some way I could use **TimelineProperties** class inside a Timeline Custom Element to bind data from Project Element directly into a Timeline's **TimelineProperties**?

## Here is my full code that works by code duplication and not using a shared **TimelineProperties** class:

1. **project.ts** - I have a parent Custom Element like this:

```js
import {TimelineProperties} from "./timeline";

@customElement('project')
export class Project {
   timeline: TimelineProperties = new TimelineProperties();
}
```

```html
<template>
   ...
   <timeline list.bind="timeline.list" loading.bind="timeline.loading" error.bind="timeline.error" />
   ...
</template>
```

2. **timeline.ts** - And child Custom Element like this:

```js
import {DataLoading} from "./api";

export class TimelineProperties extends DataLoading {
    @bindable list: Task[] = [];
}

@customElement('timeline')
export class Timeline {
    @bindable list: Task[] = [];
    @bindable loading: boolean = false;
    @bindable error: any;
    ...
}
```

```html
<template>
...
</template>
```

3. api.ts

```js
export class DataLoading {
    @bindable loading: boolean = false;
    @bindable error: any;
}
```

## UPDATE - Satisfied with this solution

Based on Ashley Grant's suggestions to use a decorator to initialize the bindings, I have modified my code based on that input and I am happy with it now. Here is my code now using the "extends" and a decorator to initialize the bindings in child classes:

```js
import {DataLoading} from "./api";

export class TimelineProperties extends DataLoading {
    list: Task[] = [];
}

// To ensure a compile time errors if property names are changed in TimelineProperties
function propertyName<T>(name: keyof T){
    return name;
}
// Now define all bindings in a decorator instead of inside the classes
function timelineBindings() {
  return function(target) {
    bindable(propertyName<TimelineProperties>("loading"))(target);
    bindable(propertyName<TimelineProperties>("error"))(target);
    bindable(propertyName<TimelineProperties>("list"))(target);
  }
}

@customElement('timeline')
@timelineBindings()
export class Timeline extends TimelineProperties {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Why not pass the full TimelineProperties object through the binding? I do that kind of thing a lot and it works great.  (Instead of binding to individual properties.)  I can post an example it this does not make sense.

Comment: @Vaccano If I understand you correctly you are referring to: "@timelineBindings(new TimelineProperties())" approach and then iterate over the object keys to initialize the bindings? If so then I was thinking about that approach also but then I lose typescript compile time checkings, with "Timeline extends TimelineProperties" I can reference "list" and other properties (from extended classes) in my methods in Timeline class and have the compile time checks. If you had other points in mind with "pass the full TimelineProperties object through the binding" I would be glad to hear about them.

Comment: There is a third way dealing with this - and I just found out how: By adding the bindable properties using a decorator. I have explained how that works overe there: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45361429/1521227

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why you are trying to create such a deep hierarchy of classes for this. These classes have one or two properties, so I'm not seeing what the benefit is of the inheritance tree. You're writing TypeScript, so you'd probably be better served by using interfaces for this stuff.

How many other places is `TimelineProperties` used in your codebase? If this is the only place then there isn't really code duplication in reality. The code duplication is caused by your insistence on using a bunch of classes to unnecessarily complicate the design.

I'm sorry if I'm misreading this from your example code, but I *very* often see developers going crazy with inheritance and such thinking it will help them not repeat themselves, but in the end the benefits of DRY are vastly outweighed by the increased complexity of the solution they produce.

So anyways, assuming there actually is a need to reuse these classes in multiple places, I would recommend using decorators to accomplish this.

For example: https://gist.run/?id=6ad573e051f53c8e163d36dc31dc36b6

*timeline-props.js*

```
import {bindable} from 'aurelia-framework';

export function timelineProps() {
  return function(target) {
    bindable('list')(target);
  }
}
```

*timeline.js*

```
import {timelineProps} from 'timeline-props';

@timelineProps()
export class Timeline {

}
```

*timeline.html*

```
<template>
  <ul>
    <li repeat.for="item of list">
      ${item}
    </li>
  </ul>
</template>
```

*app.html*

```
<template>
  <require from="./timeline"></require>

  <timeline list.bind="items"></timeline>
</template>
```

This is the exact type of use-case that decorators were created to handle.

Comment: I have removed a lot of code from my examples when creating the question and as such may seem as over engineered. If the code grows I'd like to compose them into a more comprehensible chunks (refactoring) and this parent-child separate data composition (TimelineProperties) purpose was to shrink the number of properties from project.ts element (readability is much better in Project element in that way as it contains a lot of other properties in there) , also after that step the same properties were needed in Timeline element and then it felt right to use the same class for that. ...

Comment: ... Also DataLoading class is used in many other places to show loading indicators for custom elements and class seemed a better fit for that. I came stumbled into this issue while trying to refactor the code to make it more understandable. Anyway in current code (after refactoring that part of code) it looks more reasonable from my taste of view to make this separation, from readability, maintainability point of view. It seems bindable properties inheritance would have worked very well for me in this case. But thank you a lot for your input on this. Really appreciate your quick feedback.

Comment: Bindable property inheritance might have worked well, but there's a big problem with using inheritance in an Aurelia application. When using dependency injection, inheritance becomes an anti-pattern and should be avoided if at all possible.

Comment: So when in "Parent extends <Child>", If that Child class does not have any dependency injections (because it is just a POJO class) as it is for my case then the inheritance could work ?    P.S. I have not looked into the inheritance PR code (open issue) that deep yet.

Comment: But what you've created isn't a POJO. It's a POJO that's been decorated with property decorators.

Comment: By the way, in my Intermediate Aurelia course, I teach the exact pattern I showed above for using decorators to implement "inheritance." The syntax isn't as nice as just using `extends`, but it is the correct way to accomplish stuff like this in Aurelia. There's a reason you decorate a class with `@customElement('foo')` and don't write `export class Foo extends CustomElement`.

Comment: Well, you are right. In JS after transpiling, those \@bindables I guess make it then more than POJO-s. By  "dependency injection" I was thinking you ment @inject decorators on Children or did you ment any decorators on Children, including \@bindable-s ? This current topic is related to that Inheritance PR, so might me better off to for me to continue over there I guess :)

Comment: You're correct that the class won't have anything injected in to it, but as I said, it isn't simply a POJO.

Comment: Your proposal with a decorator to initialize the bindings works well for me. I have just modified it to make it for my taste and I am pretty happy with that now.